# Altering volume without amixer or alsamixer

Tags: audio, audio-volume

On a fresh, minimal install of say, Debian (i.e. one without standard system utilities, nor a desktop environment installed), is there any way to alter the volume level or mute/unmute a device without installing anything (e.g. amixer or alsamixer)?

Comment: Define "minimal install". As the question is, it doesn't make a lot of sense - please explain *why* you want to know this. If you take away all utilities to directly access the ALSA API or hardware, then you don't have these utilities, yes. But with a shell alone you can probably bootstrap yourself into being able to write binary files, and then you can make your own utilities.

Comment: In this case a "minimal install" is straight from the netinst.iso with all "software to install" unchecked during installation.
The question itself is more a matter of curiosity rather than any specific need.
By the sounds of things there isn't an "easy" way to adjust volume without these utilities, which is was all I wanted to know.

Comment: An excellent point, and highlights the somewhat poor wording of the question. I can't make sounds without installing something else (in my case I'd install something like mplayer, though I realise that violates my "without installing anything" clause, which I specified to remove suggestions like installing pulseaudio or some other amixer like tool).

Comment: @Fox If you have a file in the right raw format, `cat >/dev/audio` works for playing a sound. I don't think you can change the volume without an ioctl.

Comment: @Fox I think `modprobe snd-pcm-oss` brings up `/dev/audio` on any Debian kernel (assuming you have audio hardware of course).